# Force passing a single parameter, to a multi-optional-parameter function

Tags: swift

Consider following function:

```
func myFunction(completion: (data: Data?, error: Error?) -> ()) { }
```

My current requirement would be to have `completion:` only accept either a `data` value or `error` value, but not both. One *must* be nil.

It's easy enough to just keep them both as optional then unwrap and check their values later, but I think it would be better if the compiler was able to inform the developer that they can't set both.

Looking at it from the other way, knowing that one of them will *always* be set to `someValue` would be even more useful.

This way you could guarantee that you'll get an `error` or `data`, and never have to worry about handling cases where they're both `nil`.

Is there currently a way to do this?

Comment: I think you are proposing an extension of the language and its type system. AFAIK, you can not relate parameters in Swift signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something of Swift it can not do. In particular, as far as I am aware, Swift has no union types. If you want something like that, you may want to look at functional or functional-inspired languages.

---

*Interlude:* If both types are structs or classes (i.e. not protocols) you can use this pattern:

```
protocol DataOrError {}
extension Data: DataOrError {}
extension ErrorClass: DataOrError {}
```

Assuming there are no other implementers of the protocol, you now have something that approaches a union type. You can switch-case over types, too:

```
switch doe {
    case let e as Error: print("Error \(e)")
    case let d as Data: print("Data \(d)")
    default: assert(false, "thou shalt not implement my dummy!")
}
```

---

Anyway, we can fake it using enumerations with associated values, which can (with limitations) be used as a poor-man's union type.

Define an enum like this:

```
enum DataOrError {
    case Data(Data)
    case Error(Error)
}
```

Now you can use `DataOrError` whereever you would like to, well, have (exactly) one of `Data` or `Error`, and `DataOrError?` for at most one.

Caller-site, you get something like this:

```
extension String: Error {} // low-effort errors, don't judge me!
func myFunction(completion: (DataOrError) -> ()) {
    completion(.Data(Data(bytes: [1,2,3,4,5])))
    completion(.Error("this won't work!"))
}
```

And callee-site:

```
var myCompletion = { (doe: DataOrError) in
    switch doe {
        case .Data(let d): print("Data \(d)")
        case .Error(let e): print("Error \(e)")
    }
}

myFunction(completion: myCompletion)
// > Data 5 bytes
// > Error this won't work!
```

---

*Design note:* You may be looking for a generalization in another direction, especially if you have many different types you want to OR with `Error`. In that case, an explicit wrapper may be a good solution, even though you sacrifice nice syntax.

```
struct TalkativeOptional<T> {
    private(set) var rawValue: T?
    private(set) var error: Error?

    init(value: T) {
        self.rawValue = value
    }

    init(error: Error) {
        self.error = error
    }
}
```

Note how exactly one of the two properties can be non-`nil`. There are two more combinations; here, you can control which you want by your choice of initializers.

Example callee-site:

```
func convert(_ number: String) -> TalkativeOptional<Int> {
    if let int = Int(number) {
        return TalkativeOptional(value: int)
    } else {
        return TalkativeOptional(error: "'\(number)' not a valid integer!")
    }
}
```

Example caller-site:

```
var a = convert("dsa2e2")

if let val = a.rawValue {
    print("a + 1 = \(val + 1)")
} else { // we know by design that error is set!
    print("ERROR: \(a.error!)")
}
```

Comment: In order to bind `d` and `e` in your first `switch`, you need to say `let` (e.g `case let d as Data: print("Data \(d)")`). Also you don't need a `default` case with the `enum` option as the compiler can see that the `switch` is exhaustive (one reason why enums are much more preferable than protocols for a union type). Also note that it's Swift convention for `lowerCamelCase` enum cases. Finally (sorry to hit you with all this), your `TalkativeOptional` doesn't guarantee that exactly one its properties is non-nil as its properties are mutable, thus making the force unwrap potentially dangerous.

Comment: All true, thanks! Still learning myself. 1) Regarding `lowerCamelCase`: that feels very weird to my Java-ridden mind. 2) Regarding  `TalkativeOptional`, good catch; I was thinking of `let`-declarations, but of course we don't control that if we return such a value to someone.

Comment: No problem, welcome to the Swift community btw :) Regarding the `lowerCamelCase`, it's a result of the overall convention of naming types with `UpperCamelCase` and everything else with lower (thus as enum cases aren't types, they're lower) ([documented here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#conventions)). Regarding your second point, you could make the properties of `TalkativeOptional` `let` constants as they're given values at initialisation, and don't need to be mutated by the implementation (you'll have to explicit set the other properties to `nil` though in the init).

Comment: I like all these examples, last being my favourite since it keeps it all bundled up nicely in once place and is extendable with more properties. Suits my use case perfectly, so thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you use an enum like this

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(String, Int)
}
```

Have a look at [Best way to handle errors from async closures in Swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957802/best-way-to-handle-errors-from-async-closures-in-swift-2) where the original answer is written in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to a result enum, you should look into a promises framework. There are a number of them, but I like [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/).

```
func myFunction() -> Promise<Data> { }
```

Here is how it's used.

```
obj.myFunction().then { data -> Void in
    // Use data, it's guaranteed to be there.
} .catch { error in
    // Handle the error
}
```